# Browserify with MongoDB and ejs not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs, browserify

Im playing around with WebRTC using node.js

I have a file called server.js that pretty basically sets up an express.io socket setup for a few things, grabs the users camera, displays the video etc. All very basic. This server.js is using ejs. I have an index file elsewhere that is shown using app.render on my index.ejs file to display it.

From this index file I would like to use MongoDB. Here is my problem.

I am using npm, so I installed browserify, trying to find a way I can use mongodb on the client-side file. I made a simple main.js

```
var MyMongoDB = require('mongodb');
// sometimes had something like this - tried numerous examples from online
// module.export.MyMongoDB = MyMongoDB;
// in various forms.
```

I then used browserify to create a .js file that could be used with  tags in my index file.

I can get this far, but then I cannot for the life of me figure out how to USE this once its included!
My page has

```
<script src="necessaryFile.js"></script>
```

But later on in my javascript area, I cannot figure out how to access mongoDB. Its not under any names it would NORMALLY be, or where it is if i require it directly from the server.js (where it works properly).

I have read the browserify page, as well as 5 or 6 random stack posts or blogposts and I cannot get this to work.

Im wondering if it may be due to using render by any chance? Or have I just done something horribly dumb here